# FileReader can not find file even though it is in working directory

Tags: java, file, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I am attempting to read from a file, however the console gives me this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: dataEx.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

This is the code that I am executing.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataEx.txt" ));
    }
}
```

This is my project structure

```
-project
  -ReadTest.java
  -dataEx.txt
```

Comment: The file is not in the current working directory, whatever you may think. `BufferedReader` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You may be interested in the `File` Class.

Comment: ...Or rather you may be interested in the `Files` class since it's 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working directory

Your path is wrong, thus the reader can not find the file. Whereever you think your current working directory should be, that is not where it is.

Execute the following code to know where it is:

```
System.out.println(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath());
```

That is the path to your current working directory. Then compare that result to your expectation. Realize that your expectation was wrong and correct the path to your file or your working directory settings.

It is hard to guess where your directory might be right now. Maybe in your `bin` folder, next to the `.class` files. You will see after executing the above code snippet.

---

### NIO

By the way, not sure what exactly you plan on doing with that `BufferedReader` but you might be interested in the newer modern file API revolving around `Files` and `Paths`:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("myFile.txt"));
```

It also has other neat utility methods for File IO, much better than the cumbersome `File` class and the clunky `BufferedReader`.

Comment: It still gives me the directory that i expected it gives me way/to/path/directory

Comment: Yeah it gives me the directory I expected

Comment: Impossible. Something has to be wrong on your side. Unfortunately it is impossible for us to tell you what is wrong if you do not provide full info. Please share the output of this snippet and the full path to your file, as reported by your file explorer.

Comment: here is my output to the snippet C:\Users\pickle\javaprojects\project

Comment: and here is the full path to my file C:\Users\pickle\javaprojects\project\ReadTest

Comment: If that is really the case, it would work, seriously. Something is fishy. Maybe you interpreted something wrong or there is some other black magic going on in your background. I doubt you will be able to fix this issue at SO. You need someone who you can screenshare to. Or to whom you could send a zip-package of your project, just to see if anyone can reproduce it. As said, the code like you shared with the output you just shared will work.

Comment: WAIT i know why im missing the src the actual full path to my file is C:\Users\pickle\javaprojects\project\src\ReadTest

Comment: However i would rather not straight up code \src into the path is there a way otherwise?

Comment: Well, there you go. Never assume, directly copy paste it out of your file explorer. Note that you should not put resource files into the `src` folder. That folder is meant to only hold source code.

Comment: ohhhh got it tysm

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by that. But that sounds like a good opportunity to ask another question here at SO :)

Comment: You don't need to code full path names into your application. You just need to run it from the correct directory, in this case the directory where the data file really is.